# Spectral clustering using techniques other than k-means?

Tags: k-means, spectral-analysis, method-comparison, k-medoids

In Spectral Clustering, the algorithm suggests performing K-means to $k$ eigenvectors of the resulted Laplacian matrix.

Can I use other clustering algorithms such as [*k*-medoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids) or other non-distance based algorithms instead of k-means, or is the algorithm designed to best respond to k-means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is to find the location of the zeros in the eigenvectors. You could use PCA or any other form of clustering.

Comment: Thank you for your response. There is a strong correlation between my data points such that the correlation matrix (`cor(X')` has a lot of elements larger than 0.9. I set any value greater 0,9 to zero to make the matrix sparse. Do you agree with that?

Comment: Why would random variables with a correlation of greater than 0.9 be forced to have a correlation of 0? When I said you could use any clustering technique, I meant it was on the eigenvectors of the Laplacian matrix. It has been seen that using different techniques produce slightly different answers. My advice is to not include personal heuristics as far as possible (i.e. the data says what it says)